# Having difficulties to understand MiniMax algorithm source code - I don't get it

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax

After studying many websites with MiniMax algorithm I found one which is the easiest to understand - well, almost as I have a problem to figure out a part of the source code. It is very well known MiniMax in Java taken from [here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javagame_tictactoe_ai.html).

Unfortunately I dont understand how the evaluation function is called. It has 6 function parameters but I don't know where these numbers are coming from (I mean zero, one and two) like below:

`score += evaluateLine(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2);  // row 0`

The function "evaluateLine" parameters are:

`private int evaluateLine(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2, int row3, int col3)`

But still I don't know what these numbers mean. Anyone can help me with it as I completely stuck.

```
       /** The heuristic evaluation function for the current board
   @Return +100, +10, +1 for EACH 3-, 2-, 1-in-a-line for computer.
           -100, -10, -1 for EACH 3-, 2-, 1-in-a-line for opponent.
           0 otherwise   */
      private int evaluate() {
  int score = 0;
  // Evaluate score for each of the 8 lines (3 rows, 3 columns, 2 diagonals)
  score += evaluateLine(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2);  // row 0
  score += evaluateLine(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);  // row 1
  score += evaluateLine(2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2);  // row 2
  score += evaluateLine(0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0);  // col 0
  score += evaluateLine(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1);  // col 1
  score += evaluateLine(0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2);  // col 2
  score += evaluateLine(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2);  // diagonal
  score += evaluateLine(0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0);  // alternate diagonal
  return score;
      }

      /** The heuristic evaluation function for the given line of 3 cells
   @Return +100, +10, +1 for 3-, 2-, 1-in-a-line for computer.
           -100, -10, -1 for 3-, 2-, 1-in-a-line for opponent.
           0 otherwise */
      private int evaluateLine(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2, int row3, int col3) {
  int score = 0;
```

Comment: `I don't know where these numbers are coming from` they are indexes in tic-tac-toe matrix, which is usually 3x3

Comment: indexes? What does it mean? First call of evaluteLine is  0,0,0,1,0,2 means that row1 = 0, col1=0, row2=0,col2=1 row3=0, col3=2 . What kind of index is this?

Comment: index of cell, 0,0 means row 0, column 0 (ie top left cell)

Comment: The 8 lines are the 3 rows + 3 columns + 2 diagonals.

Comment: Ok, i got it. So simple!